# Behaviour of IN clause in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

**Sample code:**

```
select * 
from users 
where user-id in (select user-id 
                  from accounts 
                  where user-id=@user-id)
```

I used the above code, and I don't have a `user-id` column in the `accounts` table, so instead of showing an error when I execute it, it is returning all the rows present in `Users` table.

Why is it happening like that. Can any one explain it to me?

Comment: Not possible. Can you show the table structure ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question will make sense if you have no column user-id in the table accounts. This will result in user-id being selected from the table users, resulting in all rows being returned.

I imagine you will get an error saying

```
Invalid column name 'user-id'
```

When running this script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
  [user-id] in (SELECT a.[user-id] FROM accounts a WHERE a.[user-id]=@user-id)
```

You can read more [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms178050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (thanks to ughai)

Comment: If that is true it sounds like bizarre behavior :)

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg - Actually its not. From [msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms178050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), "If a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the subquery with the table name in the outer query."

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - might be a good idea to add the msdn link and related text to make your answer perfect :)

Comment: @ughai thanks for explaining. I'm no expert but I can't see how that could ever be the desired behavior. Why would you select a column from the "outer table" in the subquery...

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg because when in other situations you will need to join within your subselect or use a column for a condition